# Internet Explorer update of cert store when smart card is inserted

Tags: internet-explorer, tomcat, ssl, browser-cache, client-certificates

I have a problem with smart card authentication in a java web app using tomcat. The problem seems to be with Internet Explorer (our organization uses version 8) and how it reads the personal certificate store in Windows.

1. If the server receives the client certificate it reads a unique ID from it, belonging to  the user and compares to the database, if it is a correct ID the user gets logged in.
2. If it does not receive any client certificate a message is displayed to the user asking for the him/her to insert the smart card in the reader.
3. There is an application on the client computer that communicates with the cardreader and a browser plugin that communicates with the application. The browser plugin can be controlled with javascript so when the user inserts the card a prompt for the PIN is displayed and the certificates on the card with the user private key is inserted to the personal store in windows.
4. After the user inserts the PIN the webpage is reloaded and now IE should be able to recognize the client certificate in the personal store when the server asks for it, this does not happen though.

Currently I have some javascript code that keeps refreshing the page until IE reads the client certificate, this does happen somewhere between 1-30 refresh, and while it is an ugly solution, a low number of refreshs might be acceptable for the users but a high number is not. It seems like IE does not read certificates directly from the windows cert store but caches them in it's own store on specific intervals (the amount of refreshs depends on when the login occurs relative to the interval), because if I go to the IE options and to the "Content" tab and view my personal store I can see the certificates immediatly after the card is inserted (even though IE can't find them for the server request).

If I press the "Clear SSL state" button in the same tab then IE immediatly can read the client certificate and pass it to the server. There is a javascript command:

```
document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache');
```

This is supposed to do the same but it just empties the cache it does not make IE able to read the client certificate when called.

If we can't get this working the only solution seems to be to ask the user to insert the card and restart the whole browser. When this is done the client certificate is allways passed to the server.

Anybody recognize this problem?